# return json object as a string in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I am trying to do an ajax call from my view where I return a json object from my controller.  However, when I try this I get the object type, but not the values as strings.  Here is my code..

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetPerson()
    {
        var _model = _person;
        return Json(_model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    static Person _person = new Person()
    {
        FirstName = "Steve",
        LastName = "Johnson",
        Age = 27
    };  
}
```

View

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>The Person</legend>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input />
                    <label>Age: </label>

                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetPerson',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) { alert(result);}
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The alert box return [object Object].  I am trying to get the string values of the "Person" object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you not gone get the data from alert you ddet to specify what variable you trying to alert

```
 success: function (result) { alert(result.FirstName);}
```

Answer (score 1):

`success: function (result) { alert(result[0].FirstName);}`
when returning a json result value you should indecate the index number following with the field name

Comment: In his case, result will be an object, not an array.

Comment: That way is to get the value of the first Firstname in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `alert(result);` to `alert(JSON.stringify(result);`  That way you can see the JSON string that's actually being returned.